# Struggling to reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, reduce

Looking for some help on the best way to combine or reduce all bills into an array of objects if the 'startDate' are equal.

From this:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "startDate": "2020-01-10T07:00:00.000Z", //Same
    "endDate": "2020-01-24T07:00:00.000Z",
    "bills": {
      "name": "Bill 1",
    }
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "startDate": "2020-01-10T07:00:00.000Z", //Same
    "endDate": "2020-01-24T07:00:00.000Z",
    "bills": {
      "name": "Bill 2",
    }
}
```

to this:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "startDate": "2020-01-10T07:00:00.000Z", 
    "endDate": "2020-01-24T07:00:00.000Z",
    "bills": [
               {"name": "Bill 1",},
               {"name": "Bill 2",}
             ]
}
```

Comment: You'll have to distribute to a hash table of unique dates which then stores an array/list of bills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go over data each item and Build an object with keys as `startDate`.

If key does not exist, add key and value.

If key already exist, append the bills.

```js
const update = data => {
  const res = {};
  data.forEach(item => {
    if (!res[item.startDate]) {
      res[item.startDate] = { ...item, bills: [] };
    }
    res[item.startDate].bills.push(item.bills);
  });
  return Object.values(res);
};

const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    startDate: "2020-01-10T07:00:00.000Z", //Same
    endDate: "2020-01-24T07:00:00.000Z",
    bills: {
      name: "Bill 1"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    startDate: "2020-01-10T07:00:00.000Z", //Same
    endDate: "2020-01-24T07:00:00.000Z",
    bills: {
      name: "Bill 2"
    }
  }
];

console.log(update(data));
```

Comment: This worked. I was trying to use reduce, which probably made it more complicated than it really needed to be. Thanks!